# On calling list values in robot framework returns an error "List '${element}' has no item in index 0"

Tags: python, list, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework, Selenium Library in Pycharm. I need to fetch product id from below table and then save it in the list

[image]

below code to create the list

```
${list}=   Create List   ${ProductID}
    ${data}=    create list    ${list}
    Append To Csv File     ProductID.csv     ${data}
```

I got values in CSV

[image]

Then calling saved values in another script like

```
${rows} =  get element count   xpath=//*[@id="YearlyReport"]/tbody/tr
    sleep  2
    log to console   Total Rows ${rows}

  ${ProductID}=     Read Csv File To List      ProductID.csv
  FOR    ${element}    IN    @{ProductID}
        Log To Console   ${element}[0]

   FOR    ${rowno}    IN RANGE    1    ${rows}+1

    Input Text    xpath=//input[@placeholder='Search ...']    ${element}[0]
    sleep   5


    ${Details} =   Get Text    xpath=//*[@id="YearlyReport"]/tbody/tr[${rowno}]/td[10]
    log to console  In Search Stage of ${Details}[0] is ${Details}
```

Getting below error

**List '${element}' has no item in index 0.** If I change value to 1 then it gives same error **List '${element}' has no item in index 1.**

Comment: looks like a foreach loop there... just use ${element}

Answer (score 2):

Working with below code.

```
${ProductID}=    Read Csv File To List    ProductID.csv
${products}=    Set Variable    ${ProductID[0]}
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{products}
Log    ${element}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info in question to help you for sure.

For example, there is no content of existing ProductID.csv ( as you use `Append to CSV file` and not `Create ...`), and there is no initial value of ${ProductID} variable, nor the test report is provided

But there is my assumptions about your case:

1. Due to the screen, your Excel file actually has an empty value for the top cell.
   So, the reader data returned by `Read CSV ...` should looks like:
   `[[], ['A1'], ['B1'], ['C1'], ['D1'], ['E1']]`.

So, the first iteration of your for-loop takes `[]` as value for ${element} variable. So, it doesn't have any element, so call to `${element}[0]` raises the exception.

2. It could be one of two cases:
   The file `ProductID.csv` already exists, and it has an empty line (newline character \r or \n or both). As you use `Append to CSV file,` the new values are appended AFTER the existing content of the file that contains a new line. And the empty line is expectedly read as empty list `[]`

Or the initial data being written into the CSV-file has an empty list as the first item.